# How to make a Kafka Kraft backup correctly?

Tags: apache-kafka, kraft

previously, to back up kafka, it was necessary to save the state of zookeeper and the data from log.dir, now we have switched to kraft to make a backup copy of the data, now we only need to copy the contents of log.dir?

Comment: Sounds correct to me. What issues are you having with this?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have a cluster of three brokers, purely in theory, it can break or someone can break it due to incorrect actions, I would like to store all the data in another Data Center and in case of data loss I could deploy it right away, since I have not worked with kraft, I want to understand that I need to backup other than copying log.dir

Comment: I'd recommend using MirrorMaker2 to properly backup to an external Kafka cluster, not just copying any data directories. But like I said, sounds like you know what to copy. What happens when you try and restore that data?

Comment: @OneCricketeer the principle of my work is to fully investigate first, and then do it, I haven't tried this method with a simple copy of log.dirs yet

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#replace_disk